# dependency tree sentiment stanford nlp

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have a dependency Tree as String. however i convert to Tree and do sentiment analysis. It gives me only -1 (not working).
I able to print the tree successfully using parse.pennPrint(), and it looks fine to me .

```
    String sentence="(TOP (S (S (NP (NNP china)) (VP (VBD experimented) (PP (IN in) (NP (DT the) (NN past))) (PP (IN with) (NP (NP (JJ various) (JJ political) (NNS systems,)) (VP (VBG including) (NP (JJ multi-party) (NN democracy,))))))) (CC but) (S (NP (PRP it)) (VP (VBD did) (RB not) (VP (VB work,) (S (NP (NN president) (NN xi) (NN jinping)) (VP (VBD said) (PP (IN during) (NP (NP (DT a) (NN visit)) (S (VP (TO to) (VP (VB europe,) (VP (VBG warning) (SBAR (IN that) (S (S (VP (VBG copying) (NP (JJ foreign) (JJ political) (CC or) (NN development) (NNS models)))) (VP (MD could) (VP (VB be) (ADJP (JJ catastrophic)))))))))))))))))))";
    int sentiment_score =0;
    try{

        Tree parse =  Tree.valueOf(sentence);
        parse.pennPrint();


        sentiment_score = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(parse);
        System.out.println("input tree, score: "+sentiment_score);  
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Printed Tree using parse.pennPrint():

(TOP
  (S
    (S
      (NP (NNP china))
      (VP (VBD experimented)
        (PP (IN in)
          (NP (DT the) (NN past)))
        (PP (IN with)
          (NP
            (NP (JJ various) (JJ political) (NNS systems,))
            (VP (VBG including)
              (NP (JJ multi-party) (NN democracy,)))))))
    (CC but)
    (S
      (NP (PRP it))
      (VP (VBD did) (RB not)
        (VP (VB work,)
          (S
            (NP (NN president) (NN xi) (NN jinping))
            (VP (VBD said)
              (PP (IN during)
                (NP
                  (NP (DT a) (NN visit))
                  (S
                    (VP (TO to)
                      (VP (VB europe,)
                        (VP (VBG warning)
                          (SBAR (IN that)
                            (S
                              (S
                                (VP (VBG copying)
                                  (NP (JJ foreign) (JJ political)
                                    (CC or)
                                    (NN development) (NNS models))))
                              (VP (MD could)
                                (VP (VB be)
                                  (ADJP (JJ catastrophic)))))))))))))))))))

Comment: The tree may be well-formed so it parses, but make no sense for the annotator due to some other structural problems. Where did you get the string representation?

Comment: Where is `RNNCoreAnnotations` coming from?

Comment: (1) I use OpenNLP chunker to get the tree (and subsequently convert to string). However I wish to use semantic prediction of stanford nlp library to get semantic classification. As I able to convert from string to tree and print it, I dont see it as structural problem in my understanding  . (2) RNNCoreAnnotations coming from edu.stanford.nlp.neural.rnn.RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(Tree tree) . thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the sentiment classifier -- your code tries to get a [nonexistent] sentiment label from a tree. Easiest would be to run the parser as well and start from raw text:

`Annotation document = new Annotation("your text");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(new Properties(){{
  setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,parse,sentiment")
}});
pipeline.annotate(document);`